# Geowebcache geoserver 2.9 caching fails

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I´m stuck with getting GWC working for one layer. Geoserver version is 2.9.
The layer in question has

```
Native Coordinatesystem: EPSG:4326
MinX: 19.0583763  MinY: 43.1548072  MaxX: 19.165252  MaxY: 43.2070563
```

I´ve created a GWC gridset based on `EPSG:4326` and calculated the gridset borders from the scope of the reference system:

```
MinX: -180  MinY: -90  MaxX: 180  MaxY: 90
```

I´ve added the gridset to my layer. On saving I already get warnings the the bounds do not overlap with a gridset. When visiting a tile and checking the return header I see:

```
geowebcache-cache-result:MISS
geowebcache-miss-reason:
```

and geoserver logs show:

```
2018-03-09 12:34:38,493 INFO [org.geoserver.gwc] - Error dispatching tile request to GeoServer
org.geowebcache.grid.OutsideCoverageException: Coverage [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] is [128, 128, 127, 127, 8], index [x,y,z] is [141, 162, 8]
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: I had this issue as long as working inside an "isolated workspace"